# Any idea how to use UDT with .NET Core and oracle client?

Tags: .net, oracle, .net-core

I have tried using .net core with oracle [.net client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnetcorebeta-4077982.html) normal oracle client, but neither of this support UDT. Does anyone succeed .net core with UDT?

Comment: Your best option is to provide [feedback](https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/windows_and_.net/odp.net) to Oracle on issue.

Comment: Maybe also look at [dotConnect for Oracle](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned *"neither of this supports UDTs"*.

There is an issue on this topic tracked by Oracle at GitHub:
[Udt with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core #56](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/issues/56)

But they are working on it ...

> [alexkeh commented on Oct 21, 2020](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/issues/56#issuecomment-713888765)
> The dev team is making good progress on UDT support for managed ODP.NET and ODP.NET Core. My expectation is that we'll deliver the feature in the first half of 2021.

... and it seems they are almost finished now.

> [alexkeh commented Jan 31, 2021](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/issues/56#issuecomment-770312212)
> It's very close. Around the end of February, we'll have a validation drop we can provide supported customers.